# Two excel files onto extended monitors

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

i want to open two (or more) excel windows on different screen (extended displays), But was not able to. I tried few solutions found on Google.

Comment: What have you tried already? What were the solutions you found on Google? What OS version do you have? need a bit more information

Answer (score 2):

Open one file via the normal method (double clicking) then right click on the Excel icon (assume you're on Windows 7 or 8) and select Microsoft Office Excel to get a new process which will allow you to use in different monitors.

Then in this second instance open the file you need via the "File" Tab.